# Exception always thrown in method called from JSP page

Tags: java, sql, jsp, postgresql, sqlexception

Here is a test query that I know works and returns 14.

```
private static final String TEST = "SELECT album_id FROM Album";
```

Every time I execute the following method, the exception is thrown and the variable x is returned instead of my album_id

```
public String getAlbumId(String email, String album_name) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(TEST);
        //stmt.setString(1, email);
        //stmt.setString(2, album_name);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        String album_id = rs.getString(1);
        return album_id;
    }
    catch(SQLException e) { String x="-1"; return x; }
}
```

The section of jsp code that calls this method is the following:

```
<table>
<%
  AlbumDao album2 = new AlbumDao();
  String myid;
  int actualid;
  for(String item : album_names) {
      myid = album2.getAlbumId(email,item);
      actualid = Integer.parseInt(myid);
      System.out.println(myid);
%>
<tr>
  <td><a href="display_album.jsp?album_id=<%=actualid%>"><% out.print(item);%></a></td>
</tr>
  <%}%>
```

I've looked at the code tens of times by now, and I can't figure it out. Any reason why this is happening?

The output of printStackTrace() is as follows (sorry for the long output):

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkResultSet(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2452)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1882)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:174)
    at photoshare.AlbumDao.getAlbumId(AlbumDao.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.index_jsp:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: Please provide the stackdump from the exception you are encountering.

Comment: Will do. Let me just add it to the question really quick

Comment: This might sound a little silly to ask but I assume you are not literally using that query?

Comment: The query shown above was a test query that I 100% know the answer to. I'm using that right now because there is only one album in the DB. Therefore, there is only one returned value.

Comment: The exception stacktrace says it crystal clear. Take some time to read it and probably google it. Most of the errors newbies see are already faced and fixed a zillion times.

Comment: Did you try doing what the exception says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `rs.next()` before  `rs.getString(1)`. The exception also hints the same.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem. Just wondering though, what does the ResultSet point to after the executeQuery() method returns? Do you do `rs.next()` to position it at the first element?

Comment: Yes, the Javadocs say, `A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set`.

Comment: 'When a ResultSet object is first created, the cursor is positioned before the first row'.The cursor points to first row only after calling 'next'. This looks sensible because sometimes you don't get any result. See section 15.2.2 in JDBC 4.1 spec for more details, http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-eval-spec/index.html

Comment: @asgs sorry didn't see your comment before posting mine